# Error : 'str' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, tree

Thanks in advance.

When I try to display tree data from sql server, I am getting the **Error:'str' object has no attribute 'children'** Please help me to fix the issue.

My Code :

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,name='root',children=None):
        self.name=name
        #self.Tid=Tid
        self.children=[]
        if(children):
            for child in children:
                self.add_child(child)

    def add_child(self,node):
        assert(isinstance(node,Tree))
        self.children.append(node)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

from anytree import Node, RenderTree
from anytree import ContStyle
import pyodbc

try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=****;database=****;trusted_connection=yes;user=****;password=****")
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from dbo.UserTree where Relation='self' order by Sno")
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    t=row[6]
    print(RenderTree(t))

except Exception as e:
    print("Error : ",e)

finally:
        cursor.close()
        cnxn.close()
```

```
FYI : output of above SQL SELECT stmt :Tree('*',[Tree('ElectronicItems',[Tree('Mobile'),Tree('TV'),Tree('Computer'),Tree('Camera'),Tree('Refrigerator')])])
```

Its working fine when I harcoded the value inside a variable.like this.,

```
t=Tree('*',[Tree('ElectronicItems',[Tree('Mobile'),Tree('TV'),Tree('Computer'),Tree('Camera'),Tree('Refrigerator')])])
print(RenderTree(t))
```

but throwing error when I dynamically pass the value from sql server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. I don't understand why you expect the definition of `class Tree` to have any effect on the rest of the code shown. What part of the code is supposed to use that class? How is it intended to use the class? If you are trying to get an instance of the class from an object-relational database - did you check that the database schema makes sense? Did you try to check the *type* of the result that you get back from the query?

Comment: Given the `__repr__` of your class, what do you expect to see when you display an instance? I don't see how it would give you a result like the one shown. Are you expecting the database's tree to use nodes based on `anytree.Node`? Then, again, what is the purpose of your own `Tree` class?

Comment: Thanks Karl. I can understand the issue now. when I hardcoded the value 't=Tree('*',[Tree('ElectronicItems',..), its referencing the Class Tree. but when I try to pass the same value dynamically..its not able to reference the Class Tree. any idea how to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the value you are getting back from the sql statement is a string. To evaluate this string, you could use [eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) to interpret it during runtime:

```py
t=eval(row[6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Christian. it works perfect !!, Thank you Karl !!

```
t=eval(row[6])
```